# Unable to Install torch for Python 3.7 - 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pytorch, conda

I am trying to install pytorch on linux based remote system. But I am getting the same error with every version of python from 3.7 to 3.11.

Command Used for installation

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

Following is the the error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Conda command used:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch

Following is the error:
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- torchvision
- torchaudio

Comment: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have tried all these commands but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual environment.

> Please ensure that you have met the prerequisites below (e.g., numpy)

> To install the PyTorch binaries, you will need to use one of two supported package managers: Anaconda or pip. Anaconda is the recommended package manager as it will provide you all of the PyTorch dependencies in one, sandboxed install, including Python.

Complete guide here:
**https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/**

[image]

Comment: All the requirements are met. The only thing that worked for me was to use conda forge but could only get torch 1.13.1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `conda install` if you meet version conflicts. You can install the `.whl` file manually.

You can find the .whl files here.

[torch, torchvision, torchaudio...](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html)

[torch](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/)

1. Download the .whl file with the version you want.
2. Install the .whl file using pip:

```
pip3 install your_package.whl
```